# rbenv install ruby BUILD FAILED

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm quite new to rbenv let alone ruby and having some difficulty diagnosing the following installation failure:

```
rbenv install 2.0.0-p0
Downloading yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/5fe00cda18ca5daeb43762b80c38e06e
Installing yaml-0.1.6...
Installed yaml-0.1.6 to /Users/Haani/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0

Downloading ruby-2.0.0-p0.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/50d307c4dc9297ae59952527be4e755d
Installing ruby-2.0.0-p0...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/50/wzjqg8d11sn7xnkrsmgr1gn80000gn/T/ruby-build.20140420110650.75863
Results logged to /var/folders/50/wzjqg8d11sn7xnkrsmgr1gn80000gn/T/ruby-build.20140420110650.75863.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling ossl_x509cert.c
compiling ossl_x509crl.c
compiling ossl_x509ext.c
compiling ossl_x509name.c
compiling ossl_x509req.c
compiling ossl_x509revoked.c
compiling ossl_x509store.c
installing default openssl libraries
linking shared-object openssl.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

See full log [here](http://pastebin.com/GMKsffJp)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the Homebrew package "readline".

```
brew uninstall readline
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew/0181c8a1633353affefabe257c170edbd6d7c008/Library/Formula/readline.rb
brew pin readline
```

Then retry installing ruby with

```
rbenv install 2.0.0-p0
```

Answer found thanks to https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/579#issuecomment-41122071

Comment: Thanks, that worked. So which line from the log tipped you off?

Comment: To be honest, all the credit goes to the person who wrote the post at https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/579#issuecomment-41122071

Comment: @Lv.BeLeCk I am having the same problem here with the latest version of Ruby. I am on Ubuntu. When I enter the brew commands I am told no such command exists, even when running git. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to update my command line tools.

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
Then
`sudo xcode-select --install`