# Getting BUILD FAILED when trying to install Ruby via rbenv on Mac OS X 10.14.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rbenv

I'm trying to install Ruby using rbenv but it keeps ending up with a BUILD FAILED message.

I've tried reinstalling Xcode, rbenv, and homebrew without any success.

I'm running:

`rbenv install 2.6.3`

My goal is to get some kind of installation success message but I keep getting BUILD FAILED after multiple attempts.

This is what I'm getting from the configuration summary:

```
Configuration summary for ruby version 2.6.3

   * Installation prefix: /Users/New32/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3
   * exec prefix:         ${prefix}
   * arch:                x86_64-darwin18
   * site arch:           ${arch}
   * RUBY_BASE_NAME:      ruby
   * ruby lib prefix:     ${libdir}/${RUBY_BASE_NAME}
   * site libraries path: ${rubylibprefix}/${sitearch}
   * vendor path:         ${rubylibprefix}/vendor_ruby
   * target OS:           darwin18
   * compiler:            clang
   * with pthread:        yes
   * enable shared libs:  no
   * dynamic library ext: bundle
   * CFLAGS:              ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}
   * LDFLAGS:             -L. -L/Users/New32/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib  \
                          -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib
   * DLDFLAGS:            -L/Users/New32/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib  \
                          -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup \
                          -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress
   * optflags:            -O3
   * debugflags:          -ggdb3
   * warnflags:           -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement \
                          -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero \
                          -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int \
                          -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 \
                          -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn \
                          -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long \
                          -Wno-missing-field-initializers \
                          -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality \
                          -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare \
                          -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value \
                          -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens
   * strip command:       strip -A -n
   * install doc:         yes
   * JIT support:         yes
   * man page type:       doc

---
    BASERUBY = /usr/bin/ruby --disable=gems
    CC = clang
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = clang -dynamiclib
    CFLAGS = -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32  -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT -fPIE -DCANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN
    CPPFLAGS = -I/Users/New32/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin18 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/12.1.0 
    DLDFLAGS = -L/Users/New32/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib  -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-pie -framework Security -framework Foundation  
    SOLIBS = -lpthread -ldl -lobjc
    LANG = en_US.UTF-8
    LC_ALL = 
    LC_CTYPE = 
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
compiling ./main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
compiling dmyext.c
compiling miniprelude.c
translating probes probes.d
compiling ast.c
compiling bignum.c
compiling class.c
. ./vm_opts.h
compiling compar.c
compiling compile.c
compiling complex.c
compiling cont.c
compiling debug.c
compiling debug_counter.c
compiling dir.c
compiling dln_find.c
compiling encoding.c
compiling enum.c
compiling enumerator.c
compiling error.c
compiling eval.c
compiling file.c
compiling gc.c
compiling hash.c
compiling inits.c
compiling io.c
compiling iseq.c
compiling load.c
compiling marshal.c
compiling math.c
making mjit_config.h
compiling mjit_compile.c
compiling node.c
compiling numeric.c
compiling object.c
compiling pack.c
compiling parse.c
compiling proc.c
compiling process.c
compiling random.c
compiling range.c
compiling rational.c
compiling re.c
compiling regcomp.c
compiling regenc.c
compiling regerror.c
compiling regexec.c
compiling regparse.c
compiling regsyntax.c
compiling ruby.c
compiling safe.c
compiling signal.c
compiling sprintf.c
compiling st.c
compiling strftime.c
compiling string.c
compiling struct.c
compiling symbol.c
compiling thread.c
compiling time.c
compiling transcode.c
compiling transient_heap.c
compiling util.c
compiling variable.c
./revision.h unchanged
compiling vm.c
compiling vm_backtrace.c
compiling vm_dump.c
compiling vm_trace.c
compiling ./missing/explicit_bzero.c
compiling ./missing/setproctitle.c
compiling addr2line.c
compiling dmyenc.c
compiling dln.c
compiling localeinit.c
compiling prelude.c
compiling array.c
compiling mjit.c
assembling coroutine/amd64/Context.S
compiling enc/ascii.c
compiling enc/us_ascii.c
compiling enc/unicode.c
compiling enc/utf_8.c
compiling enc/trans/newline.c
compiling version.c
building rb_mjit_header.h
linking miniruby
rb_mjit_header.h updated
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
generating encdb.h
building .ext/include/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.3.h
./miniruby -I./lib -I. -I.ext/common  ./tool/transform_mjit_header.rb "clang " rb_mjit_header.h .ext/include/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.3.h
encdb.h updated
./tool/ifchange "--timestamp=.rbconfig.time" rbconfig.rb rbconfig.tmp
rbconfig.rb updated
generating enc.mk
creating verconf.h
verconf.h updated
compiling loadpath.c
making srcs under enc
linking static-library libruby.2.6-static.a
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `srcs'.
generating transdb.h
/opt/local/bin/ranlib: object: libruby.2.6-static.a(dln.o) malformed object (unknown load command 1)
ar: internal ranlib command failed
make: *** [libruby.2.6-static.a] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
transdb.h updated

Transforming external functions to static:
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'Init_vm_stack_canary' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_opt_struct_aset' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_opt_struct_aref' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_eql_opt' static inline
transform_mjit_header: changing definition of 'rb_equal_opt' to declaration
transform_mjit_header: changing definition of 'rb_vm_search_method_slowpath' to declaration
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_rewrite_cref' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_push_frame' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_block_ep_update' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_cref_new_toplevel' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_frame_block_handler' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_ep_local_ep' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_rewrite_cref' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_frame_block_handler' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_block_ep_update' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_ep_local_ep' static inline
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sigbits
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'Init_vm_stack_canary' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_eql_opt' static inline
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincospi
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincospif
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincos
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincosf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnormall
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnormald
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnormalf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_signbitl
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_signbitd
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_signbitf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnanl
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnand
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnanf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinfl
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinfd
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinff
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitel
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinited
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitef
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sputc
ln -sf ../../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.3.h include/ruby-2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.3.h

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.5 using ruby-build 20190423)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/l4/1sgxbx9n6_v207xt24hb52th0000gn/T/ruby-build.20190522234118.3484
Results logged to /var/folders/l4/1sgxbx9n6_v207xt24hb52th0000gn/T/ruby-build.20190522234118.3484.log

Last 10 log lines:
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnand
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnanf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinfl
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinfd
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinff
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitel
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinited
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitef
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sputc
ln -sf ../../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.3.h include/ruby-2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.3.h
```

I'm fairly new to this and trying to learn so apologies in advance if this is a simple issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with readline you should check this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24789134/6858117) out. for further details visit this rbenv issue https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/579#issuecomment-41122071

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me.  I'm getting Error: readline: undefined method `revision' for #<BottleSpecification:0x00007fe284146220> when I try to install readline.  I did ignore dependencies when uninstalling it.  Would that cause any issues?

Comment: what brew version are you using?, try updating your brew

Comment: Also I updated the stackoverflow post link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24789134/6858117

Comment: I'm using homebrew 2.1.3 and rbenv 1.1.2.  Trying brew update gives me the same version.  RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS doesn't seem to be working either although it's giving me a different error about not being able to create GNUmakefile.

Comment: I think so.  I've tried reinstalling everything and now I'm back to the same output as when I started, even after trying RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS.

Comment: Okay, so I don't know what I did, but it works now after I was trying to figure out how to test out the make command then randomly decided to try installing 2.6.3 again.  I appreciate your help, Israel.  Thank you!