# Pod install problem with React Native on macOS

Tags: react-native, terminal, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I’m running the latest version of react native, whenever I create a new project through the terminal, I receive a message saying that I have to install pods manually by going to the iOS folder. When I do so, the pod install fails. I’ve tried running ‘sudo gem install’ and deleting and reinstalling react native.

This is the error I'm getting now when trying to run rbenv:

```
BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.1 using ruby-build 20191111)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/rh/5076xlbn4g9gzkvwk1wkjg400000gn/T/ruby-build.20191120204401.79920.wx7t9i
Results logged to /var/folders/rh/5076xlbn4g9gzkvwk1wkjg400000gn/T/ruby-build.20191120204401.79920.log

Last 10 log lines:
*** building:

    make depend
making all in crypto...
/usr/bin/perl ../util/mkbuildinf.pl "clang -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -fno-common -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB_SHARED -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM" "darwin64-x86_64-cc" >buildinf.h
clang -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -fno-common -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB_SHARED -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -I/Users/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/include   -c -o cryptlib.o cryptlib.c
/bin/sh: User1/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/include: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [cryptlib.o] Error 127
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
clang: error: no input files
```

[image: This is the $HOME directory]

Comment: can you check to see if there is `Podfile`? and can you remove `Podfile.lock` before re-installing?

Comment: There is Podfile but not Podfile.lock

Comment: i see. are you able to do a `pod repo update` and `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` before doing a `pod install`?

Comment: I just tried this and this time, I got a different error.

Comment: it seems like your pod installation and downloads got blocked. can you take a look at this [github comment](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8002)?

Comment: This doesn't seem to help. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: how about `sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods` and do another `pod install`? there are also other suggestions raised in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224627/error-on-pod-install). check it out.

Comment: Still doesn't work, any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I have already faced this problem. I don't know why, but the default Ruby version on mac causes problems.

To get over this, I use [Rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) which is Ruby versions manager.

Here's how to install it

```
brew install rbenv
```

In your **bash_profile** or **bashrc** or **zshrc** whatever put this code and don't forget to **source** your file

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Install a Ruby version with rbenv different from your actual version to be sure rbenv works.

```
rbenv install 2.5.3
rbenv global 2.5.3
rbenv rehash
ruby -v //ensure that you're now using 2.5.3 version
gem install cocoapods
```

Delete your **Pods/** **Podfile.lock** and try to run `pod install` again. It should do the trick. As I said, it worked for me and the members of my project team. You must remember not to use **sudo**.

Keep me in touch I can provide clarification if you're stuck

Comment: I received the following error when running `rubyv install 2.5.3`:

`BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.1 using ruby-build 20191111)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/rh/5076xlbn4g9gzkvwk1wkjg400000gn/T/ruby-build.20191120062653.49305.6q008u
Results logged to /var/folders/rh/5076xlbn4g9gzkvwk1wkjg400000gn/T/ruby-build.20191120062653.49305.log`

Comment: You mean you can’t even install rbenv ?

Comment: I can successfully installed rbenv but I can't successfully run the command `rbenv install 2.5.3`

Comment: Maybe this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177652/rbenv-install-ruby-build-failed) can help you

Comment: Didn’t seem to help.

Comment: Maybe try another version or restart your computer ? You have to make rbenv works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202743/discussion-between-moe-safar-and-hurobaki).